# I can't use LocalDB in my MVC project

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, localdb

Once, I tried Forces in MVC4

After some time, my enthusiasm has passed, now I'm back , I ran VS 2013 Community
I did everything according to the tutorial
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller
When you run your application and move on to /Movies I get the following error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details.

In the application event log of Windows I found a lot of mistakes differing only in the text in brackets

> The "DataDirectory" registry value is missing in the LocalDB instance registry key: {F9DBC929-EA1E-4E89-8DEF-A0C76052EBDC}

Last error

> Windows API call CopyFileW returned error code: 2. Windows system error message is: You can not find the file specified.

I decided to remove SqlLocalDB and install from scratch, but I do not know what I should remove...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IrPj.png

So I downloaded the same SqlLocalDb.msi from Microsoft.

during the installation,

> Installation of SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB  failed because a higher version already exists on the machine. To proceed, uninstall the higher version and then run SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB  Setup again.

So I tried to remove the Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDb

> Warning 26002. The following products depend on SQL sERVER 2014 Express LocalDB, dependent products might not function as expected. To avoid unexpected behavior, you should uinstall dependent products first. Do you want to uninstall SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB anyway?

In the HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\ I do not have Microsoft SQL Server. Can I update SQL Server by Visual Studio can fix this problem?

I changed Data Source on

> (localdb)\mssqllocaldb;

but it did not help

Comment: Instead of randomly uninstalling products, check what the error message means. This is most likely a permissions problem that can be solved by running Visual Studio as an administrator, or by deleting the offending key. Downgrading is never the answer but it *can* wreck your development machine.

Comment: @xxx yyy Delete the `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances\[GUID_FROM_EVENT_LOG]`  key which will resolve the lcoal db error no need to uninstall Sql server

Comment: In the HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\ I do not have Microsoft SQL Server. Can I update SQL Server by Visual Studio can fix this problem?

Comment: what `Data Source` ur giving to connect to db?

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;

Comment: Try like  `connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;.`  this

Comment: I changed but it did not work still the same error

Comment: just one more try i guess `(localdb)\.`  :P

Comment: also chk if this path exist `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances` delete the registry key:

Comment: In the registry at all has nothing to do with Microsoft SQL Server in `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Software\Microsoft\`  Changing the data source did not give

Comment: how do u say it has nothing to do with SQL server..

Comment: In Visual Studio I have updates SQL http://imgur.com/eODsbb9

Comment: Really, really thank you very much that you wanted to help me, especially you @too_cool
I updated the SQL Server by Visual Studio, then I set Data Source on `(localdb)\V11.0;` and works :)